# What is the best way to manage UI for iPhone 5 (4 inch) and other iPhones (3.5 inch)

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6

I am working on a universal **iOS** app and **UI** is completed based on iPhone 5 (4 inch display), now I have to make all the **UI** stuff look fine in older iPhones (3.5 inch displays).

I am using `UIStoryboard`,

AutoLayout = YES,

ARC = YES,

All **UI** is designed using **IB** in `UIStoryboard`.

deployment target = iOS 6+

What is the best way to manage UI for iPhone 5 (4 inch) and other iPhones (3.5 inch)

I tried  Separate  `UIStoryboard` for both screen sizes but its not working and default 4 inch `UIStoryboard` is gets loaded all the times.

please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Comment: You shouldn't need different storyboards, just auto-layout. Describe the problems you see.

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you can switch between the 3.5 inch / 4 inch layouts by pressing this button:

[image: Storyboard]

I've found it's easiest to do keep the layout in the 4 inch view and then modify the struts and springs to best accommodate the size/position. Then you can switch back to 3.5 inch and make any necessary adjustments.

Comment: I tried this already but layout disturbed for 4 inch screens whin i tried to run this in 4 inch screeen

Comment: This is the accepted way to manage the two layouts, but if you absolutely must create two different storyboards, just keep in mind that you now have 2 UI's to test

Comment: @Kamal also, struts and springs are the most pivotal part of a static UI layout

Comment: This only works in storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

identify device 4 inch or 3.5 inch in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
 UIStoryboard  *storyboard=nil;
    if ([UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {

        storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    }
    else
    {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_4" bundle:nil];
    }
    [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```